# React Component Lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To my knowledge, when some events happen, react creates a virtual-DOM from scratch and compares it to the old virtual-DOM. If that is the case, when the render method is called, react should create components and return them to compare.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class Demo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("constructor called");

    super(props);
    this.state = { dummy: 1, };
  }

  render = () => <button onClick={this.props.onChange}> button </button>;
}

class App extends Component {
  state = { num: 0, };

  onChange = () => {
    this.setState({ num: this.state.num+1 }); // mutate state to trigger a render
  }

  render() {
    console.log("rendered");
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Demo onChange={this.onChange} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

A quick console log reveals that the constructor is called the first time to mount the `Demo` component onto the page. However, subsequent renders do not create new `Demo` objects that are compared with the old virtual-DOM (since the constructor is not called).

At first, my theory was that when the constructor of `Demo` is called, it then calls the super constructor to check if a similar object with the same props already exists. But that was not the case as proven by moving `console.log("constructor called");` before calling the parent constructor.

So my question is how does react know not to create another object?

Comment: It's doesn't create new virtual trees, it simply recursively invokes the "render" method and compares the resultant diff to see what changed from the previous render and what needs to be updated to the actual DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that `Demo` is not unmounted. When you first render the app, it renders and mounts the `Demo` component and passes the `onChange` prop. But, when the callback is invoked from Demo it sets the state on App. Calling `setState` in App doesn't unmount the Demo component, so there's no need to mount it again. When the component is mounted initially is when the constructor runs. If you had a toggle on the App component that would only show the component within render if a certain condition is true, that would trigger the component to unmount.

Check out this codesandbox and play around a little: https://codesandbox.io/s/lifecycle-methods-vivn6?file=/src/Lifecycle.js.

Also, this is a cool diagram to get a sense of what's happening: https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/
[image]

The main key is that the constructor runs when the component mounts. It will only run again if the component is unMounted from the DOM and then remounted later.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But how does react know I am not trying to mount a new component with `<Demo onChange={this.onChange} />`? After all, I didn't provide a `key` so both objects will have `key = null`.

Comment: It already rendered that component to the DOM the first time and it hasn’t removed it from the DOM. When render is called again, it will generate identical markup. The key property is important when iterating over collections, specifically when sorting elements.  Basically, mounting is the first render. Once a component is rendered, react stores a reference to it and updates it when render is called again.  This article should help: https://reacttraining.com/blog/mount-vs-render/